# background image in div doesn't show

Tags: css, image

I made an empty div element to give a background image but the background image doesn't show...

HTML:

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="no">Meer informatie</li>
            <li class="no">Bestemmingen</li>
            <li>Mijn vlucht</li>
            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="yo"></a></li>
            <li>Mijn verhalen</li>
            <li class="no"> Over wowair</li>
            <li class="no">Wow Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

 <div></div>
</header>
```

CSS:

```
  header div{
    background-image: url(../images/haikudesk.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 50em;
    height: 10em;
}
```

Comment: Side note, your image element isn't closed properly `<img src="images/logo.jpg" `. WRT your background image issue, have you checked the console for errors? Is the path correct?

Comment: Its not showing in the answer

Comment: Does it work if you use a different image url? Does the div appear if you set a background color?

Comment: I don't know how but in all of a sudden it worked! Thanks for the help!

Comment: you can try to copy some image url from internet and paste instand of your image url and see if it works that means your path is't correct

Answer (score 2):

It works as per this [Pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/exzGME) are you sure the image url is correct?

```
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li class="no">Meer informatie</li>
            <li class="no">Bestemmingen</li>
            <li>Mijn vlucht</li>
            <li><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg"                                   `              alt="yo"></a></li>
            <li>Mijn verhalen</li>
            <li class="no"> Over wowair</li>
            <li class="no">Wow Contact</li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

 <div></div>
</header>

header div{
    background-image: url('https://wiki.mozilla.org/images/d/d9/Webdev_code.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    width: 50em;
    height: 10em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the url in quotes:

```
header div {
  background-image: url('../path/here');
}
```

Comment: This is a good recommendation in general but wouldn't have any effect here; the url they're using doesn't include any of the characters that need escaping in an unquoted URI.